# Octave script showing old result every time

Tags: octave, fopen, fread, fseek

I have an octave script, that is reading a text file with (fopen, fseek and fread) functions. In this file, binary data is stored.

First, I read the file in a loop like this:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt', 'rb');
fseek(fid, 0);

for i = 1:5
  data = fread(fid, 1000);
  ......
  ...<Opertions I want to do>
  ......
  ......
endfor
```

It takes 1000 bits in one iterations and computes the results for every 1000 bits.
Then I read the file from different position by changing the fseek line like below:

```
fseek(fid, 1000);
```

But still it is giving the same result as it gave for the first slot (even now I am not reading the first slot) when I read the file from the beginning.
Then I did the same thing on my other computer and their it worked for the first time, but in the second attempt it is showing the same behavior. First I thought may be there is a problem with my scripts or generated file, but then it worked fine for the first time on the other computer then I think there is some kind of problem with Octave. May be I need to clear the memory or something.

Has anyone ever faced this type of problem?

Comment: No. Are you sure your file's contents aren't repetitive every 1000 bytes? If not, are you able to reproduce this issue with a minimal example, and copy paste it here so that we can try it out? Which octave version and OS are you using?

Comment: Furthermore, can you a) check if `fseek` was successful by inspecting its return value, and b) confirm the position of the cursor each time using `ftell`?